# Three.js - Transparent object gets refracted so far over

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had created a scene with walls and objects , For the objects like door i had created a another transparent object with the object height and width, The transparent hides the wall which is very long too.I had attached the images

**Image 1 :** 
When i see through the door  the objects ( models loaded using json loader ) is visible , but other objects ( wall - created using box geometry , and surface- plane geometry ) also gets transparent.

**Image 2:** Wall is present there

**Image 3:** While looking through door the wall at left gets hide and the sky and floor beyond it is displayed

I had user the below code as material for the box geometry

```
material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xd6d6d6,
transparent: true, 
opacity: 1.5,
overdraw: 0.5 
});
```

and the material i used for the transparent object is

```
var materialRight = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xcc49c3,//violet
            opacity     :-0.1,              
            transparent : true,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            ambient: 0xea6767,
            //depthWrite  :true,
            //alphaTest:0.1,                
        });
```

I tried using `alphaTest` and `deptWrite` too - it does not work for me .

Can any one guide me , how to rectify this transparency issue.? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Values for opacity go from 0 to 1. In both cases you are outside those limits. Also, why do you have transparency set for your walls? Why do you have a transparent plane in the place of your door?

Comment: when i remove the transparent and opacity for wall, the transparent object created for door itself doesn't work

Comment: so why do you have that there anyway?

Comment: How did you create the door in the wall using Three.js? I have to create doors and windows in Walls of my 3D model using Three.js, but couldn't find a way. Please suggest.